# How can I use the TFS Power Tools Backup/Restore feature to restore an entire TFS installation from one server to another

Tags: tfs, backup

I have TFS 2010 on an existing server and want to move it to a new server. I would like to keep all of my collations intact and make the move as smooth as possible. I would also like to use the Power Tools backup/restore feature to do this. I have backups now in a network location so how can I reliably restore these onto my newly installed and patched TFS 2010 box (with no configuration)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Moving a TFS instance to a new server is a delicate procedure. The TFS Configuration database contains a lot of URI's, service accounts and other important information.

You can quickly restore a TFS backup to the same server, without issues. To actually move to different hardware or a clean installation, [follow the following (lengthy) procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can use your existing backups.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had previously stumbled onto that article. I would amend "delicate" with "painful." I'm holding out hope that someone has a suggestion for a tool that can simplify the procedure - if not, I will look at making my own PowerShell script to assist with this...

Comment: Funny, I originally wrote 'painful', then rewrote to 'delicate' :). I'm not aware of existing shared scripts that can do this. Maybe someone has it in their private collection...

Comment: If you build one, please do share :)

Answer (score 1):

+1 for @jessehouwing

But if you have the same URI's, you can do the following

After you back up TFS 2010 using TFS Power Tools 2011, then you restored the TFS 2010 back up to another SQL Server or instance, or restored in the original SQL Server which your TFS 2010 configured?

If you want backup TFS 2010 using TFS Power Tools and restore to the original SQL Server, please refer to the detailed steps in this article: [http://myalmblog.com/2010/09/12/tfs-2010-power-tools-tfs-backup-and-restore-hands-on-lab/.](http://myalmblog.com/2010/09/12/tfs-2010-power-tools-tfs-backup-and-restore-hands-on-lab/)

If you want to backup TFS 2010 and restore to another SQL Server or instance, after restore TFS 2010 database on the new SQL Server, you need to configure the new SQL Server for your TFS 2010, please refer to the detailed steps in this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252516.aspx.